# How can i get all permissions from a all tables in single run in Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I need to get permissions from all tables in single run in Kusto.

```html
// To Get Table level principals
.show tables | project DatabaseName, TableName;
let AllTables = $command_results;
.show table TableName principals (need Loop logic)
```

Now, I need to run “***.show table Table Name principals***” command for all tables in above variable in a loop.

Comment: Have you tried any approach/effort? Share the blockers/errors that occurred during the implementation.

Comment: Hi Naveen. I am not sure how to approach this requirement as loops are not allowed in Kusto. So you have any approaches or ideas?

Answer (score 0):

To get principals for tables present in your database, instead of looping through all the tables you can you below query. It will return a column name `AuthorizedPrincipals` which will have a complete set of principals present for individual tables.

**Query**

```
.show  tables  details
```

**Result**
[image]